# Why does it ask for a parameter when doing this query in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, percentage

I created a query in Management Studio that looks at the genres in a table and calculates the percentage out of the total amount of genres. This works great in Management Studio, but when I paste the code in Access a box pops up that asks for a parameter for the expression percentage.
  What should I edit in the code to make it suitable for Access?

```
SELECT genre_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS aantal, 
    (COUNT(*)*1.0 / (select COUNT(genre_name) from movieGenre)) * 100 as percentage
FROM movieGenre
GROUP BY genre_name
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

I'm guessing Access doesn't like it when I want to divide the Count(*) by a different query.
  Here's what I get back in Management Studio, which I'd like to achieve in Access too:

```
Genres | Percentage
Action | 45%
Comedy | 35%
Drama  | 20%
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think Access supports ordering by an expression (I could by wrong though) but you should be able to use your query as a derived table and then do the order by percentage like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    movieGenre.genre_name, 
    Count(*) AS aantal, 
    (Count(*)*1/(select COUNT(genre_name) from movieGenre))*100 AS percentage
  FROM movieGenre
  GROUP BY movieGenre.genre_name
  ) subquery
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by jpw, it is probably the computed column not be allowed, but you can also try ordering by the ORDINAL column of the query.. such as "order by 2 desc"